# a pop-up window is appear but just a blank frame, it don't contain two panel that I put,

Tags: java

I use eclipse IDE,I compile the Project including two class, first time I took the content of the constructor of Test class in main method ,then I run the project,a pop-up window is appear but just a frame, it don't contain two panel that I put, second time I changed just like next two file, result is same with last, no panle, I am a newbie, maybe the question looks like easy,but please explain more details, thank you!

```
//   file: Test.java
package wecanteen;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame{
    public static int NUM = 6;

    public Test() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 5));
        Test1 p1 = new Test1();
        Test1 p2 = new Test1();
        add(p1);
        add(p2);

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                p1.getjButton().setText("" + i);
                break;
            case 1:
                p1.getjButton2().setText("" + i);
                break;
            case 2:
                p1.getjButton3().setText("" + i);
                break;
            case 3:
                p2.getjButton().setText("" + i);
                break;
            case 4:
                p2.getjButton2().setText("" + i);
                break;
            case 5:
                p2.getjButton3().setText("" + i);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = new Test();

        jFrame.setTitle("this is a task");
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(320, 100);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

//   file: Test1.java

package wecanteen;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test1 extends JPanel {

    private JButton jButton; 
    private JButton jButton2;
    private JButton jButton3;

    public Test1() {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 5));
        jButton = new JButton();
        jButton2 = new JButton();
        jButton3 = new JButton();

    }

    public JButton getjButton() {
        return jButton;
    }

    public JButton getjButton2() {
        return jButton2;
    }

    public JButton getjButton3() {
        return jButton3;
    }
}
```

Comment: You never added the buttons to the panel

Comment: I am just make exercise on my book,so it looks odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your buttons:

```
public Test1() {
   setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 5));
   jButton = new JButton();
   jButton2 = new JButton();
   jButton3 = new JButton();
   add(jButton);
   add(jButton2);
   add(jButton3);
}
```

Comment: Haha! Don't beat yourself up.  Glad I could help!